# Matrix operation in python, maximum value

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have two matrixes

```
A = array([[ 12.,   0.],[  0.,   4.]])
B = array([[ 13.,   5.],[  -1.,   -5.]])
```

and I want to get a third one whose elements correspond to the maximum of the previous matrixes. For instance I would like to produce something like

```
C = array([[ 13.,   5.],[  0.,   4.]])
```

Is there any vectorial operation I could do to make the result faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to use numpy array instead of arrays. With a numpy array you have the np.where function to solve this:

```
    import numpy as np
    A = np.array([[ 12.,   0.],[  0.,   4.]])
    B = np.array([[ 13.,   5.],[  -1.,   -5.]])
    C = np.where(A>B,A,B)
    >>> C
    array([[ 13.,   5.],
    [  0.,   4.]])
```

This works like : np.where(condition, [returnvalue if true, returnvalue if false])
If you don't pass the optional return parameters, you will get an array with the indexes where the condition is true.

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.maximum`.

```
>>> np.maximum(A, B)
array([[ 13.,   5.],
       [  0.,   4.]])
```